# content type UTF-8 dose not set in responce header if SSI is enabled in IIS 7.5

Tags: utf-8, iis-7.5, ssi

I have set up UTF-8 in responce header in IIS 7.5 using following configuration in web.conifg. and this is working fine. I can see text/html;charset=UTF-8 in responce header. but this does not work if i enable SSI (server side include) module for html file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <configuration>  
      <system.webServer>
          <staticContent>
             <remove fileExtension=".html" />
             <mimeMap fileExtension=".html" mimeType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />       </staticContent>
      </system.webServer>
   </configuration>
```

Is there any other setting which i am missing. Any pointer on this will be very helpfull

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The configuration section  that you reference controls how the IIS static file handler sets the content-type header.

Unfortunately when you configured SSI, it is the ServerSideIncludeModule that handles generating the response, and this module hard-codes the Content-Type to be "text/html".  This is unfortunate behavior for your scenario.

You do have a non-so-easy option to write an IIS module which intercepts responses and changes the Content-Type as needed -> this will work against all content: static, SSI, etc.